# Tree fold in Racket

Tags: tree, racket, fold

I am a beginner at Racket and I got this question:

> - define a structure, `node`, which has these fields: `value`, `left`, `middle`, `right`. This structure represents nodes in a tree structure.
>   These fields contain the value stored in the node, the left subtree,
>   the middle subtree, and the right subtree respectively. If a subtree
>   does not exist, then the corresponding field should contain an
>   `emptyNode` as described below.
> - define a structure, `emptyNode`, to specify an empty node in the tree.
> - Write a function, `treeFold`, which takes a function, `f`, an initial value, `initial`, and a tree structure, `tree`, as parameters. It should
>   then produce a single value which is the result of using `f` to fold the
>   values in the tree (using `left`, `middle`, and `right` subtrees in that
>   order). Note that `f` is a function that takes *two* parameters. The first
>   parameter is a value from the tree and the second is the partially
>   accumulated result.

the function call should be :

```lisp
(treeFold (lambda (a acc) (+ a acc)) 15 tree)
```

tree:

```lisp
(node 7 (node 5 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
        (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
        (emptyNode))
```

the output : `47`

this is what I did so far:

```lisp
(struct node (value left middle right) #:transparent)

(struct emptyNode () #:transparent)

(define tree 
    (node 7 
          (node 5 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
          (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
          (emptyNode)))

(define (treeFold f initial tree)
  (if (emptyNode? tree)
     (emptyNode)
     (node (f initial (node-value tree))
           (node-left tree)
           (node-middle tree)
           (node-right tree))))
```

How can I get the total of the whole leaves?

any ideas or help, thanks

---

edit: so, based on the answer and discussion in its comments I got a new function but there is still a mistake and I could not find it.  here it is:

```lisp
(define (treeFold f initial tree) 
  (cond 
    [(emptyNode? tree) 
          (f initial 0)] 
    [else (f (node-value tree) 
             (f (treeFold f 
                   (treeFold f 
                      (treeFold f initial 
                         (node-left tree)) 
                      (node-middle tree)) 
                    (node-right tree))))]))
```

could you please tell me how to fix it? thank you.

---

edit: final code

```lisp
(define (treeFold f initial tree) 
  (cond 
    [(emptyNode? tree) (f initial 0)] 
    [else (f  (node-value tree)                
              (treeFold f                   
                   (treeFold f 
                        (treeFold f initial 
                             (node-left tree)) 
                             (node-middle tree)) 
                             (node-right tree)))]))
```

it works as I expected

Comment: there's still a problem with your new code. as I discuss in the answer, `collectAllStringsInWholeTree` won't work under it. there's no need to combine `initial` with `0` on the empty node. why `0`? what if it's strings we're dealing with? just `initial` is enough, there. except for that, well done. :) it defines a post-order traversal of a tree, whereas my answer suggests a pre-order one. I guess both are OK as it is not specified in the requirements. but since it is named "initial", I'd expect pre-order be the intended one. otherwise it'd be named "final" or something.

Comment: with numbers and `+` it doesn't matter, but what if it were `-`? or strings with `string-append`? then the results for pre- and post-order folding would be different, in general. i.e. `(treeFold - 100 tree)` should return `68`, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update after question was edited with new version of the function.

It is a step in the right direction. There's some correct pieces in it, and some incorrect pieces.

Functions are like boxes that can be wired together. Stuff goes in on some wires, and goes out on some others. Each box has it proper way of use: the number of wires, and the stuff it is expecting to flow into it in them.

Your new version:

```
(define (treeFold f initial tree) 
  (cond 
    [(emptyNode? tree) 
          (f initial 0)] 
    [else (f (node-value tree)                 ;; (1)
             (f (treeFold f                    ;; (2)
                   (treeFold f 
                      (treeFold f initial 
                         (node-left tree)) 
                      (node-middle tree)) 
                    (node-right tree))))]))
```

`f` expects two arguments. `(f initial 0)` *looks* right, in that regard at least. The call in `(1)` as well. But the call to `f` at `(2)` has only one argument supplied to `f`, so can't be right.

Next, to the meaning of it. The three nested calls to `treeFold` are *almost* right: we "go in" into `(node-left tree)`, i.e. the left sub-tree, with `initial` as the initial value, then we get the result from that and use *it* as the new initial value to go into the middle sub-tree, and use the computed result to go over the right sub-tree. Nice. We're ***done***. That is the *final* result we need -- no need to feed it into `f` any further. So those two calls to `f` above the three nested calls to `treeFold` aren't needed at all.

Except, what are we to do with the `(node-value tree)`? Where does it fit in? The answer is, it should be combined with the `initial` value, by way of calling `f`, and the *result* of *that* should be used as  the initial value with which we go over the *left* sub-tree; the value with which we *start* the folding.

The base case is also incorrect. We already have the `initial`, why would we need to combine it with `0` all of a sudden? And why `0`? We could be folding over a tree holding *strings*, for example, and combining strings with a number `0` wouldn't make a whole lot of sense.

No, `0` would be *supplied* as the initial value in a call to `treeFold`, like

```
(define (sumAllNumbersInWholeTree tree)
  (treeFold + 0 tree))
```

And with strings-bearing tree we could e.g. define

```
(define (collectAllStringsInWholeTree tree)
  (treeFold string-append "" tree))
```

Initial version of the answer follows. Go over its (very slightly edited) example with your new understanding. :)

---

For

```lisp
(define tree 
    (node 7 
          (node 5 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
          (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
          (emptyNode)))
```

it must be, according to the specs,

```lisp
47 == (treeFold + 15 tree)
   == (treeFold + 15 
        (node 7 
          (node 5 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
          (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) 
          (emptyNode)))
   == (treeFold + 
          (treeFold + 
              (treeFold + (+ 15 7)
                  (node 5 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))
              (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))
          (emptyNode))
   == (treeFold + 
          (treeFold + 
              (treeFold +  
                   (treeFold + 
                       (treeFold + (+ 22 5) (emptyNode))
                       (emptyNode))
                   (emptyNode))
              (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))
          (emptyNode))
   == (treeFold + 
          (treeFold + 
              (treeFold +  
                   (treeFold + 27
                       (emptyNode))
                   (emptyNode))
              (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))
          (emptyNode))
   == (treeFold + 
          (treeFold + 
              (treeFold + 27
                   (emptyNode))
              (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))
          (emptyNode))
   == (treeFold + 
          (treeFold + 27
              (node 20 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))
          (emptyNode))
   .........
```

(writing `==` for "equals"). This already gives you everything you need for a complete definition, namely that

```lisp
(treeFold + i (node v lt md rt))
==
(treeFold +
   (treeFold +
      (treeFold + (+ i v) lt)
      md)
   rt)
```

and

```lisp
(treeFold + i (emptyNode))
==
i
```

Comment: what you said is that ``` (treeFold + i (node v lt md rt)) ``` would give the total of the whole leaves right?

Comment: the leaves are all empty, there are no values in leaves. the total of values in *nodes* of `tree` is 32. `(treeFold + 15 tree)` returns 47.

Comment: first of all you need to fix your definition of `treeFold`. it's all kinds of wrong. make it follow the two rules at the bottom of this answer.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear in my question. what I meant is the total number of the whole tree including root. the treeFold function should look like this according to the question. so according to that function how could I use fold to find the total of the values even if it is a different than mine?

Comment: start with *your* tree. you need 32. `(treeFold + 15 tree)` returns 47. why? what is `(- 47 32)`? what would `(treeFold + 14 tree)` return? what should you call to get 32? would the same call then work on any `tree`, not just your tree?

Comment: the call function should look like this: (treeFold (lambda (a acc) (+ a acc)) 15 tree)  and 15 could be changed, 15 is just an example

Comment: yes I understand. so what should you call to get the correct result? what should be used instead of 15?

Comment: could be any number. the number is not important as the function works as it is supposed to be in the above question. maybe I don't understand what do you mean exactly but could you please read the question above  (the third point )so you can get what I mean. thanks.

Comment: I'm not asking clarifications from you. I'm giving you hints so you could see that my answer already answers your question. :) I want to help you be able to write the code yourself.

Comment: so based on what you gave I got a new function but there is still a mistake and could not find it. could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: here it is ``` (define (treeFold f initial tree)
  (cond [(emptyNode? tree)
      (f initial 0)]
        [else(f (node-value tree) (f (treeFold f (treeFold f (treeFold f initial (node-left tree)) (node-middle tree)) (node-right tree))))]))
```  thank you

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer which was most helpful to you, after -- *if* -- you feel like you've got your answer. :) see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: you helped me a lot and I appreciate that. one last attempt could you take a quick look, please.

Comment: (define (treeFold f initial tree) 
  (cond 
    [(emptyNode? tree) 
          (f initial 0)] 
    [else (f (initial (node-value tree))                 ;; (1)
             (treeFold f                    ;; (2)
                   (treeFold f 
                      (treeFold f initial 
                         (node-left tree)) 
                      (node-middle tree)) 
                    (node-right tree)))])).    still not working

Comment: you're welcome. if you want, edit to add your final code into the question, and I'll take a look.